# Multiple components within a file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Says I have component A

like

```
export default class ComponentA extends components {
   render(){
      return() //use componentB here?
   }
}

class ComponentB extends components {

}
```

how can I create another component and use it within ComponentA?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> How can I create another component and use it within ComponentA?

There are two possible ways of doing that:

**1-** Define the component in the same file, exporting of that component will be not required because you will use that component in the same file.

**2-** Define the component in another file then export that component. Importing of component will be required in this case.

---

We can create as many components as we want in the same file, and we can use those components in the same way as we use HTML tags `div, span, p` etc.

**Example:**

Using `ComponentB` inside another component `ComponentA`:

```
export default class ComponentA extends components {
   render(){
      return(
           <div>
              {/*other code*/}
              <ComponentB />            // notice here, rendering ComponentB
           </div>
      )
   }
}
```

Define `ComponentB` in same file like this:

```
class ComponentB extends components {

}
```

Define `ComponentB` like this in another file:

```
export default class ComponentB extends components {

}
```

Answer (score 10):

Just use it, like any other component:

```
export default class ComponentA extends components {
   render() {
      return <ComponentB />; // Use ComponentB here
   }
}
class ComponentB extends components {
  render() {
    return <div>I'm B</div>;
  }
}
```

Example:

```js
/*export default*/ class ComponentA /*extends components*/ extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return <ComponentB />; // Use ComponentB here
   }
}
class ComponentB /*extends components*/ extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>I'm B</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ComponentA />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are in the right track.

```
export default class ComponentA extends React.Component {
   render(){
      return(<ComponentB />);
   }
}

class ComponentB extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (<h1>Hello world! This is Component B</h1>)
    }
}
```

or better yet, use `stateless components` like so: (if it's a really dumb component)

```
const ComponentB = () => (<h1>Hello world! This is Component B</h1>);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want many component in one file and use it another file. create and export them seperately.

```
export const FirstComponent = () => {
return <h1>First Component</h1>;
};

export const SecondComponent = () => {
return <h1>Second Component</h1>;
};
```

In Main.js file

```
import { FirstComponent, SecondComponent } from "./ManyComponent.js";
export default function App() {
return (
<div className="App">
  <FirstComponent/>
  <SecondComponent/>
</div>
);
}
```

If you want component to be used within same file.In Main.js file

```
export default function App() {
return (
<div className="App">
<FirstComponent/>
</div>
);
}
const FirstComponent = () => {
return <h1>First Component</h1>;
};
```

Comment: This post was answered in 2017, this is digging